# Stacking images in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html, image, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` list with two `<li>`s within it as follows:

```
<ul>
            <li id="sc-1">
            </li>
            <li id="sc-2">
            </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS for these elements is as follows:

```
#sc-1{
    background-image:img/banner1.jpg no-repeat center;
    overflow:hidden
    position: relative;
    z-index:5;
}

#sc-2{
    background-image:img/banner2.jpg no-repeat center;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index:4;
}

ul{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li{
    display:block;
    width:92.3%;
    height:300px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Is there any possible way to stack these images so `sc-1` is ontop of`sc-2`?

Comment: Check the syntax on your CSS. This `background:img/banner2.jpg) no-repeat center;` isn't valid.

Comment: I believe I fixed that in the edit, but I was originally using a url for the background.

Comment: Actually it's still wrong. You're using the shorthand background notation with the background-image property. Either change what you have to something like `background:url("img/banner2.jpg") no-repeat center;` or break up the rules into their separate property values.

Comment: Is there a particualar reason why you're not just doing `<img src="">`

Comment: @R.Underwood I've been trying many things to get this to work. I believe that was the first thing I attempted.

Comment: Hmm, so you basically want two images on top of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set position absolute on the li elements in question. Also when declaring background shorthand in this instance, you just use `background` not `background-image`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/t9b8c177/

```
#sc-1{
    background: url(myImage1.jpeg) no-repeat center;
    overflow:hidden
    z-index:5;
}

#sc-2{
    background: url(myImage2.jpg) no-repeat center;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:4;
}

ul{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li{
    width:92.3%;
    height:300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```